# aws s3 rails carrierwave picture uploading not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I was working with  s3 and aws trying to set up my rails app. All of its functions are working except for the picture uploader. The thing is the picture uploader works just fine on the local server. I have connected the the code to the s3 bucket. But all I get is the file name when I upload. What can be wrong with my method.

here is the associated files.

```
# picture_uploader.rb
# encoding: utf-8

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end


  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

## micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2500 }
  validate  :picture_size
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy  
  acts_as_votable  
  acts_as_commontable
  is_impressionable

  def set_success(format, opts)
    self.success = true
  end

  def self.search(search) 
    where("content LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end  

  private

    # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the uploader, One easy thing to try is to call `mymodel.picture.store!`, that might give you more information, maybe even an error message.

Comment: I tried your recomendation Thomas but it gave me an error saying that picture is an undefined method. If you would take a look at my  micropost.rb picture is clearly defined. So why would it be saying this?

Comment: here is the specific error `NoMethodError: undefined method picture`